# overlay two mp3 and repeat smallest mp3 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I searched lot but I can't find exact solution. And also I am new in ubuntu and don't know technical detail of music files. Actually I want to overlay 2 mp3 file. Suppose I have two 
Input files

```
A.mp3 ==> duration 03:00
B.mp3 ==> Duration 07:00
```

Now I want C.mp3 (Output file) which is combination of A.mp3 and B.mp3. But here what I want "A.mp3 file should play till the end in C.mp3. means if A.mp3 file music will stop after 03:00 minute then it should start immediatly till 07:00 minute (Duration of B.mp3)."

I tried following command but that is not what I am exactly want

```
ffmpeg -y -i A.mp3 -i B.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" -c:a libmp3lame C.mp3
```

above command will overlay two file. but A.mp3 will not repeat once it finish.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the movie source filter

```
ffmpeg -i long.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=short.mp3:loop=999[s];[0][s]amix=duration=shortest" c.mp3
```

Comment: Perfect solution. it is works like charm

Comment: What can I do to delay the "short.mp3" for say 10 seconds ? I want the short audio to fade in at the 10th second and then loop until the long audio ends

Comment: Add adelay filter after the amovie

Answer (score 0):

The most transparent way to achieve this, is to manually loop: Automatic loop works only in very new versions of ffmpeg, which might not be available in many distros.

First create a concat file `A.ffconcat`, that repeats A 3 times:

```
file 'A.mp3'
file 'A.mp3'
file 'A.mp3'
```

Now adapt your command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i A.ffconcat -i B.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest" -c:a libmp3lame C.mp3
```

Comment: my input files are dynamic . how can I know which file should i repeat how many times ?

Comment: I normaly write a script running the input files through `ffmpeg -i filenam 2>&1 | grep Duration` to find the length, then calculate the multiplication factor. If you know, which file is longer, you can just repeat the other e.g. 1000 times, no problem.

Comment: ok thank you. Can you tell me how to create concat file (As you mentioned in answere) ?

Comment: The concat files look just as in my answer: Repeat `file 'filename.mp3'` as often as needed

Comment: Splendid!!  it is working as expected But this very lengthy solution. Can you suggest alternative or small solution. thank you once again.

Comment: If you have a newer ffmpeg, you can use the `loop` feature. Be advised, that this is not portable to older distros, as the ffmpeg version carried there has no (or no reliable) loop feature.